# Failed Facebook Authorization Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to make a class to handle all my interactions with Facebook. I am passing the the Login activity I created to the FacebookConnector object (the object in question) to store the  credentials and etc. Please view the video to see what I am dealing with http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OkHEy9Mh1hc. Below is the FacebookConnector class with the App Id edited out

```
package it.stick;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FacebookConnector {

private static final String APP_ID ="************";
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"user_likes","read_stream", "user_photos", "email","photo_upload", "offline_access", "publish_actions"};

private static final String TOKEN = "access_token";
private static final String EXPIRES = "expires_in";
private static final String KEY = "facebook-credentials";

private Facebook facebook;

private Activity activity;


/** Saves applications credentials */
public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook){
    Editor editor = activity.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
    editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
    return editor.commit();
}

public boolean restoreCredentials(Facebook facebook){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = activity.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
    facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
    return facebook.isSessionValid();
}

public FacebookConnector(Activity activity){
    facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
    this.activity = activity;
}

// Creates new Facebook session and stores credentials
public void login(){
    // 1.Restores previous credentials 
    //2.Creates and saves new session if previous session is not valid
    restoreCredentials(facebook);
    if(!facebook.isSessionValid()){
        facebook.authorize(activity, PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());
    }
}
public boolean isSessionValid() {
    return facebook.isSessionValid();
}

public void logout(){
    try {
        facebook.logout(activity.getApplicationContext());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void postToWall(String message){
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("message", message);
    parameters.putString("description", "topic share");

    try{
        facebook.request("me");
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if(response == null || response.equals("") || response.equals("false")){
            showToast("Blank response from facebook.");
        }
        else{
            showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall.");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        showToast("Failed to post to wall. We fucked up :(");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener{

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        saveCredentials(facebook);
        postToWall("logged on to Stick.it");            
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        showToast("Authentification with Facebook failed!");            
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
        showToast("Authentification with Facebook failed!");        
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        showToast("Authentification with Facebook failed!");
    }

}

public void showToast(String message){
    Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

Here is the log cat:

```
02-01 22:39:39.459: W/KeyCharacterMap(637): No keyboard for id 0
02-01 22:39:39.470: W/KeyCharacterMap(637): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-01 22:39:46.299: D/dalvikvm(637): GC_EXPLICIT freed 91K, 50% free 2744K/5447K, external 3745K/3903K, paused 1017ms
02-01 22:39:46.999: D/webviewglue(637): nativeDestroy view: 0x303080
02-01 22:39:48.239: D/dalvikvm(637): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 54K, 51% free 2706K/5447K, external 3331K/3903K, paused 735ms
02-01 22:39:52.139: D/Facebook-WebView(637): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=touch&client_id=228461823905169&scope=user_likes%2Cread_stream%2Cuser_photos%2Cemail%2Cphoto_upload%2Coffline_access%2Cpublish_actions&type=user_agent&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess
02-01 22:40:12.209: D/Facebook-authorize(637): Login failed: com.facebook.android.DialogError: The connection to the server was unsuccessful.
02-01 22:40:12.279: D/Facebook-WebView(637): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=touch&client_id=228461823905169&scope=user_likes%2Cread_stream%2Cuser_photos%2Cemail%2Cphoto_upload%2Coffline_access%2Cpublish_actions&type=user_agent&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess
02-01 22:46:14.119: W/KeyCharacterMap(637): No keyboard for id 0
02-01 22:46:14.119: W/KeyCharacterMap(637): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

I have cleared the browser cache and the app data. I have checked the key hash and I have copied and pasted the App ID multiple times into the app.

Comment: sorry I'm new to stack. still getting used to the culture around here

Comment: that is ok, keep sharing knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure, you have added your application's signature to application setting, as:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sig

Comment: I completed the process exactly how they said

Answer (score 0):

Without the `onActivityResult()` method in the Activity you are trying to login with, the login will Facebook, because the android sdk then invokes the `authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data)` method.

Comment: What do you mean by "the login will Facebook"?

Comment: i have the same issue , facebook autherizationexception invalid api method  ,  do you have any solution ,  ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51552152/facebook-callback-invalid-api-method-android